# Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git como resolver?

Tags: git

Bom dia, estou aprendendo a usar o git e preciso fazer o check out de um branch.

Fiz o clone no git:

```
$ git clone https://teste@bitbucket.org/teste/teste-site.git
Cloning into 'teste-site'...
remote: Counting objects: 10818, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7681/7681), done.
remote: Total 10818 (delta 2982), reused 10588 (delta 2849)
Receiving objects: 100% (10818/10818), 420.92 MiB | 3.22 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2982/2982), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (11415/11415), done.
```

E após isso fiz o comando:

```
$ git checkout master teste-site.git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Porém me retorna este erro

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Como resolvo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você dá `clone` o git cria um nove diretório para o repositório. Você tem que rodar o `checkout` de dentro desse diretório.

Tente fazer um `cd teste-site`

Se você não desejar especificar o nome do diretório a ser criado, acrescente-o ao final do comando:

```
$ git clone https://teste@bitbucket.org/teste/teste-site.git meu-diretorio
```

Se já estiver no diretório em que deseja fazer o clone do repositório, você pode utilizar o ponto:

```
$ git clone https://teste@bitbucket.org/teste/teste-site.git .
```

Answer (score 1):

Para trocar de branch basta utilizar o comando:

```
git checkout nome-da-branch
```

Se a branch não existe e você quer criar:

```
git branch minha-branch
git checkout minha-branch
```

O comando que você utilizou é invalido, pois aponta pra um diretório que não utiliza o git.

Comment: O problema é que ele não entrou do diretório em que o repositório foi clonado antes de fazer o checkout do branch. A resposta do hugomg é a correta, acredito

Comment: "O comando que você utilizou é invalido, pois aponta pra um diretório que não utiliza o git."

Foi o que eu coloquei, e minha intenção foi mostrar um pouco sobre esses comandos básicos do git, já que podemos ver que ele não tem muita familiaridade.